# How to create record in CRM by Azure AD authentication?

Tags: c#, azure, dynamics-crm

I create a Native client application. I have got access token result from Azure AD by the article given below: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531009.aspx
code give below:

```
Uri serviceUrl = new System.Uri(CrmServiceUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web");
            string _oauthUrl = "https://login.windows.net/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/oauth2/authorize";  // DiscoveryAuthority
            String resource = "https://****.crm.dynamics.com/";
            authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(_oauthUrl, false);
            //custom test code
           AuthenticationResult result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource, _clientID, serviceUrl, PromptBehavior.Auto);

            return result.AccessToken;
```

now my question is this, How i can create service proxy from that "Access token" to make CRUD operations?
is it possible to create record in dynamic crm using access token or not?
your response should be appreciated.
thanks.